# Tricky Recursive Function

Tags: c#, recursion

```
public class look
{
    public int takeALook (int a)
    {
        if (a == 1)
            return 1;
        else if (a == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return takeALook(a-2) + takeALook(a-1);

    }
}
```

Main program,

```
int a = 6;

look lk = new look();

int r = lk.takeALook(a);

Console.WriteLine("r is" + r);
```

the answer is 8. but can anyone please explain why? It's confusing me because it is calling itself 2x.

Comment: Take debugger and see yourself.

Comment: Haven't you heard of **Fibonacci number**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: All you've done is write the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Konstantin yes I know about the fibonacci, but I'm confused on following the logic of the function itself on how to make it simple to understand. I tried to debug but can't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
takeALook(0) == 0
takeALook(1) == 1
takeALook(2) == takeALook(0) + takeALook(1) == 0 + 1 == 1
takeALook(3) == takeALook(1) + takeALook(2) == 1 + 1 == 2
takeALook(4) == takeALook(2) + takeALook(3) == 1 + 2 == 3
takeALook(5) == takeALook(3) + takeALook(4) == 2 + 3 == 5
takeALook(6) == takeALook(4) + takeALook(5) == 3 + 5 == 8
```

Comment: Great! thanks. you really know how to keep it simple for me to understand :)

Answer (score 3):

It boils down like this:

```
takeALook(6) =>
(takeALook(4) + takeALook(5)) =>
(((2 + 3)) + ((3 + 4))) =>
((((0 + 1) + (1 + 2))) + (((1 + 2) + (2 + 3)))) =>
((((0 + 1) + (1 + (0 + 1)))) + (((1 + (0 + 1)) + ((0 + 1) + (1 + 2))))) =>
((((0 + 1) + (1 + (0 + 1)))) + (((1 + (0 + 1)) + ((0 + 1) + (1 + (0 + 1)))))) =>
0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 =>
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modified your program with a tracer that may come real handy for any recursive function.

```
const string space = "  ";
static string StrMultiplier(string str,int multiplier)
{
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(str,multiplier).ToArray());
}

static int F(int a,int level = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}->F({1})",StrMultiplier(space,level),a);//Trace line
    if (a == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (a == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return F(a-2,level + 1) + F(a-1,level+1);

}
```

Result:

```
->F(6)
  ->F(4)
    ->F(2)
      ->F(0)
      ->F(1)
    ->F(3)
      ->F(1)
      ->F(2)
        ->F(0)
        ->F(1)
  ->F(5)
    ->F(3)
      ->F(1)
      ->F(2)
        ->F(0)
        ->F(1)
    ->F(4)
      ->F(2)
        ->F(0)
        ->F(1)
      ->F(3)
        ->F(1)
        ->F(2)
          ->F(0)
          ->F(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little image showing the recursion as a tree. Trimmed the childs where they had already been calculated[image]